# Whatsapp otp verification wso2 is 5.10

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Whether in wso2is can do otp via whatsapp? if can do it, please let us know how to configure. thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no WhatsApp OTP authenticator as I recall. But, this shouldn't be an issue as it shares the same logic as SMS or EMAIL OTP authenticators.

1. Generate a random code.
2. Send notification (SMS, Email or Whatsapp)
3. Prompt portal to enter the OTP.
4. Validate OTP.

As this logic matches with that of SMS OTP authenticator, you can simply write a custom outbound authenticator extending/referring to [identity-outbound-auth-sms-otp](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-sms-otp/blob/master/component/authenticator/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/authenticator/smsotp/SMSOTPAuthenticator.java) authenticator's source. Instead of triggering an SMS, you can change the logic to call the Whatsapp API to send a message.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio provides an API for WhatsApp [1]. You can use the generic WSO2 SMS OTP authenticator [2] and configure it to send messages to users via WhatsApp. The only difference in the configuration on the WSO2 IS side is the `from` and `to` parameters of the HTTP payload.

```
Body=$ctx.msg&To=whatsapp:$ctx.num&From=whatsapp:+111222333
```

WhatsApp provides their own API [2] as well, but the set up it seems to be bit complex. If you set it up successfully, I believe you can integrate with the exciting WSO2 SMS OTP authenticator [2] for this as well.

1. https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api
2. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/configuring-sms-otp/
3. https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api

Comment: Hi Sajith, I use a free provider that is nexmo.com. when I use SMSOTP with the following link `https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=1234567&api_secret=asdf1234&from=NEXMO&to=621234567&text=hallo` it works. For whatsapp is it like this? `https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=1234567&api_secret=asdf1234&Body=hallo&To=whatsapp:6212345&From=whatsapp:+112233` is not working. any advice to fix problem? thanks a lot Sajith

Comment: @IhsanJazuli through Twilio supports it, we can expect Nexmo to support it in the same way. If you look at the Nexmo documents, their payload is way different from Twilio. It also it seems we need to have valid WhatsApp business account for that.
https://developer.nexmo.com/messages/concepts/whatsapp